# Want to change home page url in top nav, but can't figure out how

Tags: 2013, navigation

I have built a site with top nav but the url for my home page is incorrect. When I try to use the edit links feature, that home page link disappears. How can I edit this so my users can go to the correct page. Image attached.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To update navigation in SharePoint 2013 you'll go to site settings(it's found under the settings gear), then navigation, after you open navigation you'll scroll down a little until you see the section called Structural Navigation. Select the link you want to edit then click on edit and follow the wizard that pops up. Make sure you select the OK button twice or your changes won't be recorded. You click on on the wizard that pops up and at the bottom of the navigation page.